# FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to run a flutter app locally on my web browser (chrome). I do the following steps:

```
flutter channel stable
flutter config --enable-web
flutter run -d chrome
```

when I run it, it starts fine, and opens chrome but it doesn't load anything, and then throws this error:

```
"FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app."
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:5005:15)
at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:63723/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:252:42)
at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
at http://localhost:63723/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

how would I fix this?

edit:

```
void main() async{


WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Comment: Can you include your main method

Comment: @YeasinSheikh just updated. is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the Flutter Firebase setup steps here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

Specifically, make sure you don't miss the following 2 steps:

1. In the terminal, run `flutterfire config`
2. In main.dart, make sure to add this code snippet:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#configure-firebase), flutterfire config will auto-create a FirebaseOptions class for you.

Comment: ok I will try rn

Comment: I have to go find credentials from teamate so may be a while.

Answer (score 0):

Start with `firebase init` command and follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

once you are done, you will get `firebase_options.dart` like t

```dart
main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(YourApp());
}
```

[image]

You will use `DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform`

Comment: ok I will try rn

Comment: I have to go find credentials from teamate so may be a while.

Comment: check your firebase console